# EhCache + hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, ehcache, second-level-cache

I have the following problem:
I have a query which return me 35 results and I would like to keep in second level cache:

```
public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        Session session = this.sessionfactory.getCurrentSession();
        String queryString = "from com.ewave.upromotions.objects.Product product where product.active=:active";
        Query query = session.createQuery(queryString); 
        query.setBoolean("active", true);
        query.setCacheable(true);
        query.setCacheRegion("productCache");
        List<Product> products =query.list();
        return products;
    }
```

My object is the following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="products",schema="test11")
@Cacheable
@Cache( usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Product implements Serializable {

//all setters and getters ommited:

}
```

my ehcache.xml file is in /src/ directory:

```
<ehcache>  
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>  
    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000"  
        eternal="false"  
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"  
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"  
        overflowToDisk="false"/>  
    <cache name="hibernate.test.org.hibernate.cache.UpdateTimestampsCache"   
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"  
        eternal="false"  
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"  
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"  
        overflowToDisk="true"/>  
    <cache name="hibernate.test.org.hibernate.cache.StandardQueryCache"   
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"  
        eternal="false"  
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"  
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"  
        overflowToDisk="true"/>
     <cache name="com.vanilla.objects.Product"
        maxElementsInMemory="300"
        eternal="false"
        overflowToDisk="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="600"  
        timeToLiveSeconds="600"  
        />  
       <cache name="productCache" 
       maxElementsInMemory="100" 
       eternal="true" 
       overflowToDisk="false" />

</ehcache>
```

and my Hibernate configuration is:

```
<props>
    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop> 
    <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop> 
     <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop> 
  <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop> 
  <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.SingletonEhCacheProvider</prop>
  <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
  <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_configuration_file_resource_path">/ehcache.xml</prop>
  </props>
```

My problem is the following: when bringing page for first time I see the select which brings all 35 results:

when I refresh page, instead of bringing 35 objects from cache I see 35 select statements which queries objects by id one by one.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was happening to me when query was cached but objects were not. In you sample code I see that query refers to `com.ewave.upromotions.objects.Product` but you have cache region defined for `com.vanilla.objects.Product`. And you didn't provide any cache region to the `Product` class. So I'd suggest that you explicitly specify cache region for `Product` and define it in cache configuration. To start, I would try the same region for query and object, just to see if it works, and then try separate configurations.